# Логика работы express.use

Tags: node.js

Когда я передаю данные через app.use это post or get запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `app.use([path,] callback [, callback...])`
>
> Mounts the specified middleware function or functions at the specified
>   path: the middleware function is executed when the base of the
>   requested path matches path.

Если вы задали `path`, то `callback` будет выполнятся для каждого запроса на указанный путь, вне зависимости от http-метода. Если `path` не задавать, то он будет вызываться для каждого запроса, если вы не прервете цепочку мидлварей  (забудете или специально не вызовете метод `next`)